# Python/OpenCV getting started with videos

Tags: python, opencv, windows-10, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run the first code at this page, "Capture vídeo from camera":

http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

on cv2.videoCapture(0), I replaced 0 with the vídeo name - it's saved on the same directory of the .ipynb file. It returns the following error:

```
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ce45564bb1af> in <module>()
  9 
 10     # Our operations on the frame come here
 ---> 11     gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 12 
 13     # Display the resulting frame

 error: C:\conda\conda-bld\work\opencv-3.1.0\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:7456: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::ipp_cvtColor
```

How could I fix it? I'm working on windows10.

Comment: The error means that either your video isn't being loaded correctly and the frame is empty, or the frame is in gray scale. Can you check that after you read the video?

Comment: Command ret, frame = cap.read() ret value is false, which means it is not loading the file. But I don't understand why.

Comment: Probably because of the format of the video you are loading. May be also the path, how are you reading it? Can you update it in the question?